# Find closest polygon from point and get its attributes?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, proximity, st-distance, knn

Given a set of points and a set of polygons, I am trying to find for each point what the closest polygon is and bring over the attributes from that polygon to the point (together with the actual distance). Ideally, I would end up with the original set of points with 2 more fields: `'distance'` and `'polygon_id'`.

I'm trying to do so with the following query (using `ST_DWithin` to limit the calculations)

```sql
CREATE TABLE test AS
SELECT t1.point_id, t1.geom, t2.polyg_id, (ST_Distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)) as distance
FROM points t1, polygs t2
WHERE ST_Dwithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, 100)
ORDER BY (ST_Distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This query is just returning one record though. The 'LIMIT 1' is acting on the whole result. How can I make that 'LIMIT 1' act on the results for each segment individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a *(K)NN* search, the running table must be parsed in a loop; PostgreSQL offers the `LATERAL` statement that can be appended to any `JOIN` to do so (among other useful things). Specifically, it passes the current row of the parent table (left hand side of the join) to the `LATERAL` subquery (right hand side of the join), where it's column values can be accessed and evaluated.

PostGIS has the [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) distance operator (informally known as *KNN* operator) that is designed to use the spatial index when used as parameter to the `ORDER BY` statement, and is the core concept of high performance spatial *(K)NN* searches:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS
  SELECT t1.point_id,
         t1.geom,
         t2.polyg_id,
         ST_Distance(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS distance
  FROM points AS t1
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT polyg_id,
           geom
    FROM   polygs
    WHERE ST_Dwithin(geom, t1.geom, 100)   -- will likely be unnecessary
    ORDER BY
           t1.geom <-> geom
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS t2
;
```

**Notes:**

- a spatial index on `polygs` is mandatory
- always run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on all tables involved (or the whole DB if you have that moment), after larger changes to the data/index or prior to potentially long running queries, to update the table statistics used by the planner to determine the best approach

Comment: the note about database maintenance (`VACUUM ANALYZE`) might be of high interest concerning your other question about multiple joins (I did a quick test on 2.5M lines vs 250K polygons with my `EXISTS` construct and had results in under a minute on a mid tech machine!)