# Reducing the processing time when handling millions of 3D points to 3D lines in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, spatial-analyst, knn

I am trying to calculate the minimum distance between 16 millions of 3D points and 3D lines.

The query is working for more or less 1 million data, but after that, it took so long and never ends. All the tables have spatial index.

The query is:

```
SELECT
    public.points.orden,
    st_length(st_shortestline(public.points.point_geometry, public.line01.geom)) as line01_length,
    st_length(st_shortestline(public.points.point_geometry, public.line02.geom)) as line02_length,
    st_length(st_shortestline(public.points.point_geometry, public.line03.geom)) as line03_length,
    st_length(st_shortestline(public.points.point_geometry, public.line04.geom)) as line04_length
ST_3DLENGTH(ST_3DSHORTESTLINE(public.points.point_geometry, public.line01.geom)) as line01_3dlength,
ST_3DLENGTH(ST_3DSHORTESTLINE(public.points.point_geometry, public.line02.geom)) as line02_3dlength,
ST_3DLENGTH(ST_3DSHORTESTLINE(public.points.point_geometry, public.line03.geom)) as line03_3dlength,
ST_3DLENGTH(ST_3DSHORTESTLINE(public.points.point_geometry, public.line04.geom)) as line04_3dlength
into public.lengthdist
FROM public.points, public.line01, public.line02, public.line03, public.line04
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.points);
```

After, I select the min distance:

```
SELECT public.lengthdist.orden,
    min(line01_length),
    min(line02_length),
    min(line03_length),
    min(line04_length),
    min(line01_3dlength),
    min(line02_3dlength),
    min(line03_3dlength),
    min(line04_3dlength)
FROM public.lengthdist
GROUP BY public.lengthdist.orden
```

And also y set the endpoint for each min line with `ST_EndPoint`, and I have the same problem.

I tried with `CREATE TABLE - INSERT INTO` statement as well, same results. Also with an `UPDATE`. Also, I tried with just `ST_SHORTESTLINE` without `ST_LENGTH`.

How can I do to reduce the never-ending processing time?

I am working in Windows 10 x64, 16GB RAM.

```
DB Version: 11
OS Type: windows
DB Type: desktop
Total Memory (RAM):16 GB 
CPUs num: 4
Connections num: 20 Data Storage: ssd
max_connections = 20
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 4GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
work_mem = 22573kB
min_wal_size = 100MB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2
```

P.D.: I've `VACUUM ANALYZE` all tables too.

Comment: Do you have a spatial index on your point table? That should help boosting the process significantly. See: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html

Comment: @julien Yes, I have spatial index in all tables, including points table

Comment: Actually, a spatial index is useless in your example; you are cross joining all tables, and expect an output for every combination. A `CREATE TABLE AS (...)` should perform a lot better; the `SELECT ... INTO` is not really optimized for large insertions. **However**, I am not sure what your overall goal might be; if it is to **find the *one* closest point (or its distance) to each of your lines**, this is the wrong way.

Comment: @geozelot Every point has an order number (it is not a primary key, several points have the same order number), after the calculation, I would like to get the min distance between points to the lines for each order, but it could be different for every line, so that is why I am trying to calculate the length first for all points. If I try to search the closest point to each of my lines I only get one point, and I would need one for every order type

Answer (score 4):

**Updated methodology:**

A more versatile, and *a lot* more performant way is to use an index driven *(K)NN* approach:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.lengthdist;

CREATE TABLE public.lengthdist AS (
    SELECT  ln.id AS ln_id,
            cat.orden AS orden,
            ST_Distance(pts.geom, ln.geom),
            ST_3DDistance(pts.geom, ln.geom)
    FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS id, geom
        FROM    public.line01
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS id, geom
        FROM    public.line02
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 AS id, geom
        FROM    public.line03
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4 AS id, geom
        FROM    public.line04
    ) AS ln
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT orden
        FROM   public.points
        GROUP BY
               1
    ) AS cats
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT  id, geom
        FROM    public.points
        WHERE   orden = cat.orden
        ORDER BY
                geom <-> ln.geom
        LIMIT   1
    ) AS pts
    ORDER BY
            1, 2, 3
);
```

This assumes

- a spatial index on all `geom` columns
- a `BTREE` index on `public.points.orden`

and runs a *(K) Nearest Neighbor* search on each set of points defined by `orden` via a double `CROSS JOIN`.

*Execution time on the setup as described in comments is 2.5 seconds.*

For more info on the overall concept:

- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)
- [Get barrier edge id](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283794/get-barrier-edge-id/283797#283797)
- [Find closest polygon from point and get its attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338312/find-closest-polygon-from-point-and-get-its-attributes/338328#338328)
- [How to UPDATE with LATERAL Nearest-Neighbour query?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/how-to-update-with-lateral-nearest-neighbour-query/278362#278362)

---

**Old answer:**

If it's the **minimum distance per group** of points **to each line** that you need, better `ST_Collect` the points by the desired category and get the `ST_Distance/ST_3DDistance`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.lengthdist;

CREATE TABLE public.lengthdist AS (
    SELECT  ln.id AS line_layer_id,
            pts.orden,
            ST_Distance(ln.geom, pts.geom) AS dist2d,
            ST_3DDistance(ln.geom, pts.geom) AS dist3d
    FROM    (
        SELECT  orden,
                ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
        FROM    public.points
        GROUP BY
                orden
    ) AS pts
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT  1 AS id, geom
        FROM    public.line01
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS id, geom
        FROM    public.line02
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 AS id, geom
        FROM    public.line03
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4 AS id, geom
        FROM    public.line04
    ) AS ln
    ORDER BY
            ln.id, pts.orden
);
```

*An example query with 16 million points and 4 lines finished in under 30 seconds, on a mid tech setup.*

Note that

- spatial indexes are irrelevant here
- having a table for each individual line is somewhat pointless within a RDBMS; also, cross joining multiple tables (with >1 rows) has some serious side effects! I `UNION ALL`'ed them into a single table and added their table suffix as id
- if your geometries are in any geographical reference system, output distance units will be *degrees*, which are useless as a measure; you may want to `CAST(geom AS GEOGRAPHY)` (or `::GEOGRAPHY`) both `geom` columns in `ST_Distance`, or use `ST_DistanceSphere/ST_DistanceSpheroid`. `ST_3DDistance` does not support the `GEOGRAPHY` type. Adding spheroidal distance calculation adds *significant* overhead to the overall query performance!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is amazing. It is working properly separated but when I put it all together it is taking so long again (waiting more than 2 hours and it is not ending). Could you share what it is your setup? Maybe I have something wrong about the configuration. I am trying this on a Windows 10 x64, 16GB RAM. About the geoms columns, I think I will not have any problem because I am working within srid 25830 for all tables. I try a little piece (1000 rows) and it is fine with the units.

Comment: @Pin_Eipol On Linux Laptop, 32GB RAM, 8 CPUs Intel-I7; (custom) PostGIS 3.0.0, PG 10; testing with 16 million globally random points (EPSG:4326) and 4 lines (both 2D and no spatial index). However, those lines consist of an average of 10 vertices only; having a few orders of magnitude more vertices, as is not unlikely for derived LineStrings, will increase computation time significantly. The same goes for the math behind `ST_3DDistance`, if you have actual Z-Values assigned to each vertice. Other factors may be DB page size/amount, how fragmented that data is, *work_mem* settings, etc.

Comment: @Pin_Eipol updated the methodology to use the mighty `<->` operator for *(K) Nearest Neighbor* searches; I haven't had the time to write this up yesterday.

Comment: I'm going to edit my original post. The lines and points are in 3D with srid 25830. The lines have about 130 vertices per line and a length of 50 km. I will try now your new approach and I will let you know.

Comment: 3 hours ago I started the new process, still waiting

Comment: @Pin_Eipol how many distinct `orden` are there?

Comment: In this case 283875

Answer (score 0):

Since you are computing distance between every pair, spatial indices don't help, the computation has to be done regardless of the index.

But since you only care about the minimum distance, you don't need every single pair. If you do want to use index, you need to use it in filter. How to do it? If you can guess the approximate minimum distance, add a filter to only return the points within (`ST_DWithin` function) some `k * guessed-min-distance`, with `k` being something between 2 and 10, depending on how confident you are about your guess. The idea is to get as little results as possible (less is faster), but not an empty set. If you got some results - great, select shortest one. If you got no results - increase search radius, until you find points.

See also couple resources - this one from PostGIS how to use box for faster search (that is not guaranteed to be precise):

https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html

and one from BigQuery how to use script to do this search

https://medium.com/@mentin/nearest-neighbor-using-bq-scripting-373241f5b2f5.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Michael but I am afraid it could not work because I can not have the approximate minimum distance and it is impossible to guess. Also, I would like to automatize it so if I have to check it for every time I do it it would take so much more time than using a QGIS tool or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the program so that the minimum distance is always known as it goes along so you don't need to waste time calculating it every time, i.e. just update a variable whenever a new minimum is reached, so you don't need to calculate it, then it should be known instantaneously at any given point in time.