# Replacement for pgr_pointToEdgeNode for pgr 3.0

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, pgrouting, knn

I am working through the book 'pgRouting: A Practical Guide' and have come across a function that has been deprecated.  The function is `pgr_pointToEdgeNode`. Is there a similar function I can use to convert a point to a vertex_id based on closest edge?

This is [a link to the function](https://docs.pgrouting.org/v2.1.0-rc1/src/common/doc/convenience/point_to_edgenode.html) from version 2.1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case not (have you checked the docs?), use a simple *(K)NN* search:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, <point>) < 0.5
         THEN source
         ELSE target
       END as node
FROM   edges
ORDER BY
       geom <-> <point>
LIMIT   1
;
```

`ST_LineLocatePoint` in the `CASE` finds the fraction of line length of the projected point from `<point>` on the closest `edge.geom`, and selects either `source` or `target`.

A spatial index on `edges` is mandatory.

---

You can outsource the `<point>` creation into a CTE if you want.

You could also wrap this up in a function, but note that for a batch solution on a *table* of points (or *more than one* point) you'd better `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` the points table/expression to a *(K)NN* subquery. See e.g.

- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)
- [Get barrier edge id](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283794/get-barrier-edge-id/283797#283797)
- [Find closest polygon from point and get its attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338312/find-closest-polygon-from-point-and-get-its-attributes/338328#338328)
- [How to UPDATE with LATERAL Nearest-Neighbour query?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/how-to-update-with-lateral-nearest-neighbour-query/278362#278362)

Comment: Yes I checked the docs for pgr.  I read through most of the manual and couldn't find any information about the pgr_pointToEdgeNode or a replacement for it.  I know KNN search and this function was basically a wrapper for that search.  I was hoping there was something similar in the latest version of pgr.  I suppose I will create my own function using something similar to your answer.  Another method using the pgr vertices table is `SELECT id FROM ospr.ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <-> 
        ST_SetSRID( ST_Point(-77.009003, 38.889931), 4326) limit 1`

Comment: I guess that function predates some major improvements to the `<->` operator that aren't easily implemented in an extension. But that's only a guess. Writing a function for one point is fine, better use the inline SQL solution for batch searches. Note that you may get different results with your alternative, as a vertex may be closer to point even if the point is right next to an edge.

Comment: That makes sense.  You are correct, your example should provide the best results.  What makes me curious is why this function was deprecated.  I thought features were usually deprecated because their functionality was replaced by a different function.  I assumed this was the case with this function but I could not find any similar functions in pgr.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The function was deprecated to reduce the number of functions that need to be maintained and documented. A few functions made it into pgRouting over the years that didn't bring much value, so it was decided to focus on the core functionality.